# tar + tar not open all files

Tags: linux, solaris, tar, shell-scripting

When I want to view the following tar file , then tar show the following three files

from /var/tmp

```
       tar tvf  fix.tar 

       install.sh
       /usr/cti/apps/swp/dir/script1.sh
       /usr/cti/lib/swp/dir/script2.sh
```

.
.

but when I want to open the files to their directories

then I get error about /usr/cti/lib/swp/dir/script2.sh ,

please advice why tar cant open the script2.sh under  /usr/cti/lib/swp/dir ?

from /var/tmp

```
       tar xvfp  fix.tar 
       install.sh
       /usr/cti/apps/swp/dir/script1.sh
       tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
       /usr/cti/lib/swp/dir/script2.sh
```

Comment: You don't say what directory you're in when doing this, but have you tried looking for `./usr/cti/lib/swp/dir/script2.sh` (note leading dot)?

Comment: lead dot ? I dont have !

Comment: You misunderstand; `.` refers to the current working directory.  I'm suggesting that, whatever directory you're in when you run the `tar xvfp` command, you look for `usr/cti/lib/swp/dir/script2.sh` **under that directory**.  Sorry not to have been clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define an output directory with the `-C` option. The files will be extracted to the 'root' of the filesystem/harddrive by setting it to `/`

So to extract your archive you should try the following command:

```
tar xvfp fix.tar -C /
```

This way the files `script1.sh` and `script2.sh` will be extracted to `/usr/cti/apps/swp/dir/`